# How to fix Ubuntu upgrade?

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade

Can`t upgrade ubuntu to newest version, get this errors:
[image: while update manager starts]

[image: while press Continue]

I tried to fix the errors through Synaptic, but the program did not see the broken packages. I also tried to fix errors using the terminal command, but it did not help

```
    $ sudo apt-get install -f
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

so how to fix this strange error?

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to to is to run on a terminal:

> `# apt-get update`
>
> `# apt-get dist-upgrade`

The output from the upgrade could give a bit more information about what has happened.

If the issue does not get resolved by dist-upgrade then you might have a problem in your source.list files. In that case, we need to know what is in them, so you need to share what's in the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and also what's in every file inside `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`.

Comment: after going through this drama myself my conclusion is not to upgrade from the OS gui. Boot into a terminal and do it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the version name with the new Ubuntu version name (e.g trusty to xenial) in /etc/apt/sources.list and any others in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* feel free to use sed.

Then:

- apt-get update
- apt-get upgrade
- apt-get dist-upgrade